# Tripartite system, three qubit system and tripartite entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, terminology, quantum-entanglement

I get confuse about the term used.

Can anyone help me to explain:

1. Tripartite system.
2. Three qubit system.
3. Tripartite entanglement.

I really need help for me clarify these term.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) A system comprised of 3 subsystems

2) A quantum system described by the linear combination of three bits of data. A bit is a property that has two options. For example a 3 qubit system will be *measured* in one of 8 states, 111 110 100 010 011 000 001 101.

3) A system comprised of 3 entangled subsystems

Comment: A 3-qubit system has 8 *basis* states. Its state can be a linear combination of those states.

Comment: Further question.  For eg, may I assume subsystem A= qubit 1, subsystem B=qubit 2, subsytem C=qubit 3?

Comment: Like craig said, if each subsystem has exactly 2 basis states

Comment: correct me please of if I wrong. 1.That mean the qubit not equal to subsystem.  2. the subsytem is made up from the state(combination of qubit)?

Comment: 1) Correct, a qubit is just a binary characteristic of a quantum entity. 2) The state of a one qubit system can be any combination of %s that add up to 100, technically there are infinite possible states because it's state is it's probability to be 0 or 1, not the 0 or 1 themselves.